# Should I use wchar_t or int16_t or char16_t for a bit map.

Tags: c++

I have a requirement to use a bit map. Basically, an array of `wchar_t` or `int16_t` or `char16_t` is needed for processing digits of a group of few hundred integers.

What should be preferred? Are there any advantages of using one over the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a bit map, perhaps consider using the [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Quoting from the link:

> The class template bitset represents a fixed-size sequence of N bits. Bitsets can be manipulated by standard logic operators and converted to and from strings and integers.

The advantage is that it is very easy to extend the number of bits to an arbitrary number. The constructor can take integral types to initialize the bitset.

Consider the example from this [documentation article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_at):

*Input*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    std::bitset<8> b1(42);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < b1.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << "b1[" << i << "]: " << b1[i] << '\n';
    }
    b1[0] = true; // modifies the first bit through bitset::refence
    std::cout << "After setting bit 0, the bitset holds " << b1 << '\n';
}
```

*Output*

```
b1[0]: 0
b1[1]: 1
b1[2]: 0
b1[3]: 1
b1[4]: 0
b1[5]: 1
b1[6]: 0
b1[7]: 0
After setting bit 0, the bitset holds 00101011
```

Comment: Hope it is efficient over the approach I was about to take. BTW if I don't want to use `bitset`, then what should be preferred over the three?

Comment: You should use the type that has the number of bits that you need. A few hundred integers doesn't sound like a lot to me, so it should be pretty quick work either way.

Comment: Ohh ok. I need 10 bits, one for each digit. Thanks!

Comment: `"I need 10 bits, one for each digit.`" I have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: @Saksham You need only 4 bits to store each digit.

Answer (score 1):

How many flags do you need? If you need 8 use a char, if you need 16 use a short. Only use as much space as you need, but be sure you don't over optimize and paint yourself (or project) into a corner.

If you don't know how it works each flag is nothing more than a friendly name for a power of two that occupies a particular bit in the integer.

1 is the first bit
2 is the second bit
4 is the third bit
8 is the fourth bit
etc...

For example, if you had two flags 
READ_ACCESS = 2  (0010)
WRITE_ACCESS = 8 (1000)

Your set your flags to Read/Write then your integer would have a value of 10 (1010).

So a character has 8 bits, which would allow you to have 8 flags.
The only benefit to one choice over another is size. If you have an embedded device, choose wisely, if you have a typical desktop make a liberal choice like a long and leave yourself some room to wiggle.

Comment: +1 for recommending the built-in types and not getting carried away by the C99 fixed-size typedefs.